# Is it possible to mount an IDE HDD to act as a boot HDD on a virtual machine?

Tags: hard-drive, virtual-machine, pata

Is it possible to mount an IDEE HDD to act as a boot HDD on a virtual machine?

My computer has a SATA drive, and I have connected an IDE (PATA) HDD. Now I need to set that IDE HDD as a boot drive on some virtual machine.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux as a host machine?

Comment: Recreate the VHD files on the ide drive?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7

Comment: Which VM software are you using?